# Backbone collection view url firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

So my application below is actually firing "FIRE!" in the console twice on page load. Not sure why backbone is firing the url function twice when I am only seeing the one fetch being made. Any ideas as to why this might be causing it to fire twice?

```
    window.ScheduleApp = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {}
    };

    window.template = function(id) {
        return _.template($('#' + id).html());
    };

    //Define the Game Model.
    ScheduleApp.Game = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            this.gameId = this.get('Id');
            this.gameTime = this.get('Time');
        }
    });

    //Define the Games Collection that contains Game Models.
    ScheduleApp.Games = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: ScheduleApp.Game
    });

    //Define the Day Model.
    ScheduleApp.Day = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            this.games = new ScheduleApp.Games(this.get('Games'));
            this.games.parent = this;
            this.gameDayGDT = this.get('GeneratedDateTime');
            this.gameDayDate = this.get('Date');
        }
    });

    //Define the Days Collection that contains the Day Models.
    ScheduleApp.Days = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: ScheduleApp.Day,
        url: function() {
            console.log('FIRE!');
            return '/js/test.json'
        },
        parse: function(data) {
            var parsedSchedule = JSON.parse('[' + data.STUFF + ']');
            return parsedSchedule;

        }

    });

    ScheduleApp.DayCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.container', //Container where the views get rendered to.

        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
        },
        render: function(event) {

            if (this.collection.length === 0) {
                $('.container-hidden').show();
            }

            //Cycle through collection of each day.
            this.collection.each(function(day) {

                var dayView = new ScheduleApp.DayView({
                    model: day
                });

                this.$el.append(dayView.render().el);

            }, this);
            return this;
        }
    });

    ScheduleApp.DayView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'div', 
        className: 'game-date', 
        template: _.template($("#gameSchedule").html(), this.model),
        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this.model, "reset", this.render);
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });


    var daysList = new ScheduleApp.Days();

    daysList.fetch({
        reset: true,
        update: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function(collection, response) {
            //console.log(collection);
        },
        error: function(model, resp) {
            // console.log('error arguments: ', arguments);
            // console.log("error retrieving model");
        }

    });

    //create new collection view.
    var daysCollectionView = new ScheduleApp.DayCollectionView({
        collection: daysList
    });
```

Comment: You can get a better idea by substituting `console.log('FIRE!');` with `console.log(new Error().stack);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All **models** belonging to a **collection** build their URLs based on the **collection URL**, as stated [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url). My guess would be that your collection is calling the method once, then your model / models place the second call, in order to build the **model URL**.

Then again, this method seems pretty harmless to me: it's just a *getter*. I'd rather place the `console.log` call in the `Collection#parse` or `Model#initializer` methods, and count how many times it gets invoked there.

Comment: Seems the Collection#parse gets fired once. So youre saying that the fact that the url gets fired twice is harmless?

Comment: By _harmless_ I mean that the method is only returning a string (you can actually set it up as a variable, you don't need the function). And the cause for the second call is probably the model building it's own URL, just like I've pointed out in the Backbone docs.